# Cloning a partial image from a different thread is very slow

Tags: c#, multithreading, image, clone, picturebox

I'm having a problem cloning a partial bitmap (Area defined by a rectangle) from another thread in C#.

For understanding:
In my application (Windows Forms) a user can define multiple areas on which different image processing functions are performed (e.g. a color or a Text is recognized). The images are provided by a frame grabber (30fps). As some algorithms, like OCR, take very long, they should be computed in background workers or threads.

My problem:
When I clone my bitmap in my main thread using
((Bitmap)pictureBox1.Image).Clone(rectangle,((Bitmap)pictureBox1.Image).PixelFormat);

the application is doing this very quickly (below 1ms for a 50x50 rectangle).

When I clone it from a different thread, it takes much more time (about 20ms+).

When I clone the whole image using ".Clone()" (without a rectangle) there is no difference from which thread this method is called. It takes the same time.

Does someone know why cloning just a part of the image does take much more time when the method is called from another thread as the thread that owns the image?

Thank you in advance.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find out why the cloning procedure does not work as quick as it should calling it from another thread, but I finally found a workaround for the copy problem:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa457087.aspx shows a copy function, which works fast called by threads, which do not own the image.

I wrote an image wrapper using this copy function. Works fine so far

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Threading;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace FeatureConfigurator
{
    public class ThreadSafeBitmapWrapper
    {
        public event EventHandler<EventArgs> onImageChanged;
        ReaderWriterLockSlim thisLock;

        Bitmap iImg;

        public ThreadSafeBitmapWrapper()
        {
            this.iImg = new Bitmap(1,1);
            this.thisLock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim(LockRecursionPolicy.NoRecursion);
        }

        public ThreadSafeBitmapWrapper(Bitmap img)
        {
            this.iImg = img;
            this.thisLock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim(LockRecursionPolicy.NoRecursion);
        }

        public Bitmap GetImage()
        {
            Bitmap img;
            this.thisLock.EnterReadLock();
            try
            {
                img = this.iImg;
            }
            finally
            {
                this.thisLock.ExitReadLock();
            }
            return img;
        }

        public void SetImage(Bitmap img)
        {
            bool success = true;
            this.thisLock.EnterWriteLock();
            try
            {
                this.iImg = img;
            }
            catch
            {
                success = false;
            }
            finally
            {
                this.thisLock.ExitWriteLock();
                if (onImageChanged != null && success)
                    onImageChanged(this, new EventArgs());
            }
        }

        public Bitmap CloneImage()
        {
            Bitmap clone;
            this.thisLock.EnterReadLock();
            try
            {
                clone = new Bitmap(iImg);
            }
            finally
            {
                this.thisLock.ExitReadLock();
            }
            return clone;
        }

        internal Bitmap CloneImage(Rectangle rectangle, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat pixelFormat)
        {
            Bitmap clone;
            this.thisLock.EnterReadLock();
            try
            {
                Stopwatch w = new Stopwatch();
                w.Restart();
                Debug.WriteLine("clone " + w.ElapsedMilliseconds);
                clone = iImg.Clone(rectangle, pixelFormat);
                Debug.WriteLine("new BMP " + w.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            }
            finally
            {
                this.thisLock.ExitReadLock();
            }
            return clone;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Code from Microsoft C# Help page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa457087.aspx
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="section">The region on the containing image, which should be copied</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public Bitmap CloneImage(Rectangle section)
        {
            // Create the new bitmap and associated graphics object
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(section.Width, section.Height);
            // Sets the lock to protect the copy procedure
            this.thisLock.EnterReadLock();
            try
            {
                using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
                {
                    // Draw the specified section of the source bitmap to the new one
                    g.DrawImage(iImg, 0, 0, section, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                this.thisLock.ExitReadLock();
            }
            // Return the bitmap
            return bmp;
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this will help someone with the same problem.

Regards